# Show that closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am taking a metric spaces class, and I am struggling to show how to prove that the closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is  $\mathbb{R}$. Taking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19044/how-to-prove-closure-of-mathbbq-is-mathbbr) question's answer as a reference, I have done the following:

**My Attempt**

We want to show that for every real number $r$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exist an at least one $q$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|r-q| \lt \epsilon$ which will mean that complement of closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is empty in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ must equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $r$ be a real number. Then, there exist at least one $q$ such that $|r-q| \lt \epsilon$ holds. I am not sure if I can choose $q$ such as:

> Write $r$
> in decimal expansion, and let $q$
> be the rational that has the same decimal expansion as $r$
> up to the $n$th digit after the decimal point, and terminates there.

Since we are in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and we cannot choose $q$ to be a rational that has the same decimal, since rational are excluded, and I am not sure if we can choose a real and non-rational number that holds to be true.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Take a rational number to the desired precision then cut off the tail and truncate the digits of $pi$ to make it irrational.

Comment: @CyclotomicField How do you know the resulting number isn't itself $r$?  You need to tweak this very slightly.

Comment: Let $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Define $a_n = q + \frac{\pi}{10^n}$. Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = q$.  Assume by contradiction that $\frac{\pi}{10^n}$ is rational, and we know that $10^n$ is rational, then $\pi$ is rational. The same proof goes for $ q + \frac{\pi}{10^n} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Kuzja How do you know $a_n \notin \Bbb Q$?

Comment: Just pressed enter instead of shift+enter, edited in the full proof.

Comment: @CyclotomicField:  did you mean *concatenate* when you typed *truncate*?

Comment: @RobertShore: Why is $q=r$ a problem? Then for sure $|r-q|<\varepsilon$? Isn't that sufficient? OP asks for $q\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Did you intend to write that the complement **of the closure** of $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is empty in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited it.

Comment: @RobertShore How can the resulting number be $r$, which is in $\mathbb{Q}$, when we have created $q$ using an irrational number? The tail of the newly created number $q$ cannot be rational since we are adding the digits of $\pi$ at the end, right?

Comment: You defined $r$ as a real number, not necessarily a rational number.

Comment: @RobertShore I now understand what you mean, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ by the Archimedean property, such that $2<\varepsilon N<\varepsilon 10^N$. Define

$$q:=10^{-N}\lfloor 10^{N}r\rfloor+\Big(\pi-10^{-N}\lfloor 10^{N}\pi\rfloor\Big),$$

such that $$|r-q|=|10^{-N}\underbrace{(10^Nr -\lfloor 10^Nr\rfloor)}_{\in[-1,1]}-10^{-N}\underbrace{(10^N\pi-\lfloor 10^N\pi\rfloor)}_{\in[-1,1]}|\le2\cdot10^{-N}<\varepsilon.$$

**Note:** Suppose $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\pi = q-10^{-N}\lfloor 10^{N}r\rfloor+ 10^{-N}\lfloor 10^{N}\pi\rfloor\in\mathbb{Q}$, which is contradictory, i.e. $q\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.

*(Following the idea of [CyclotomicField](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464974/cyclotomicfield))*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof based on cardinality.  I'll assume you know that $\Bbb Q$ is countable and (via Cantor's diagonalization proof or in some other way) that $\Bbb R$ is not countable.

First, note that $f(x) = \tan^{-1} x$ provides a $1$-$1$ surjection $f: \Bbb R \to U$, where $U$ is an open interval.  That means the open interval $U$ is uncountable.  By translating and scaling $U$ via another $1$-$1$ surjection, you can easily see that *any* open interval of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.  In particular, any ball of the form $B(r, \varepsilon)$ is uncountable.

Let $V=B(r, \varepsilon)$ be any open set.  $V \cap \Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q$ must be countable because $\Bbb Q$ is countable.  Also, $V=(V \cap \Bbb Q) \cup (V \setminus \Bbb Q)$, so since $V$ is uncountable and the union of two countable sets is countable, $V$ can't be the union of two countable sets.  Since $V \cap \Bbb Q$ is countable, this means $V \setminus \Bbb Q$ must be uncountable.  In particular, $V \setminus \Bbb Q \neq \varnothing$ so any ball contains an irrational number outside its center.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Find $q\notin \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x-q|<\epsilon$.

Comment: But how do we know that such $q$ exists?