# Prob. 24, Chap. 4 in Baby Rudin: Any continuous real function satisfying this condition is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Here is Prob. 24, Chap. 4 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Assume that $f$ is a continuous real function defined in $(a, b)$ such that 
>   $$ f \left( \frac{ x+y }{2} \right) \leq \frac{ f(x) + f(y) }{2}  \ \tag{0} $$
>   for all $x, y \in (a, b)$. Prove that $f$ is convex.

My effort:

> We need to show that
>   $$f \left( (1-\lambda) x + \lambda y \right) \leq (1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda f(y)  \ \mbox{ for all $x, y \in (a, b)$ and for all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ }. \ \tag{1} $$
>
> First, we show that (1) holds for all numbers $\lambda$ of the form
>   $$\lambda \colon= \frac{k}{2^n} \ \mbox{ for all } \ n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \ \mbox{ and for all integers } \ k \mbox{ such that } \ 0 \leq k \leq 2^n. \ \tag{2} $$
>
> For $n= 0$, we can have either $k= 0$ or $k=1$, and so 
>   $$\mbox{ either } \ \lambda = 0 \ \mbox{ or } \ \lambda = 1,$$
>   and (1) holds trivially in either one of these two cases.
>
> For $n=1$, we see that $k$ can be $0$, $1$, or $2$, and then $\lambda$ is $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$, or $1$. For the first and the last cases, the inequality (1) holds trivially as we have discussed above, while for $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$, (1) follows from (0) in the hypothesis of this problem.
>
> Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n \geq 2$, and assume that (1) holds for all natural numbers $i$ such that $i < n$.
>
> Now in (2) if $k$ is a non-negative even integer, then we can write $k = 2m$ for some non-negative integer $m$ and so $\lambda = \frac{m}{2^{n-1}},$
>   which implies by our induction hypothesis that (1) holds for this $\lambda$.
>
> So we assume that in (2), $k$ is an odd (positive) integer. Then $k$ is an integer such that 
>   $$1\leq  k \leq 2^n - 1,$$
>   and thence $\frac{k\pm 1}{2}$ are also integers such that 
>   $$0 \leq \frac{k-1}{2} \leq 2^{n-1} - 1 \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ 1 \leq \frac{k+1}{2} \leq 2^{n-1}.  \ \tag{3} $$
>   Now let $$ s \colon = \frac{ \frac{k-1}{2}}{2^{n-1}} \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ t \colon= \frac{ \frac{k+1}{2}}{2^{n-1}}. $$ 
>   Then by (3) we can conclude that $s$ and $t$ are in a range for which (1) holds by our induction hypothesis. That is, 
>   $$f\left( (1-s)x + s y \right) \leq (1-s)f(x) + s f(y) \ \mbox{ and } \ f\left( (1-t)x + t y \right) \leq (1-t)f(x) + t f(y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in (a, b). \ \tag{4} $$
>
> Moreover we note that 
>   $$\frac{s+t}{2} = \frac{ \frac{ \frac{k-1}{2}}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{ \frac{k+1}{2}}{2^{n-1}} }{2} = \frac{k}{2^n} = \lambda, \ \tag{5} $$
>   and so for all $x, y \in (a, b)$, we see that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> f\left( (1-\lambda) x+ \lambda y \right) &= f \left( \left( 1- \frac{s+t}{2} \right) x + \frac{s+t}{2} y \right) \ \mbox{ using (5) above } \\
> &= f \left( \frac{ \left( (1-s)x + sy \right) + \left( (1-t) x + ty \right)}{2} \right) \\
> &\leq \frac{ f\left( (1-s)x  + sy \right) + f\left( (1-t) x + ty \right)}{2} \ \mbox{ by (0) above } \\
> &\leq \frac{ \left( (1-s)f(x)  + s f(y) \right) + \left( (1-t) f(x) + t f(y) \right)}{2} \ \mbox{ using (4) above } \\
> &= \left( 1 - \frac{s+t}{2} \right) f(x) + \frac{s+t}{2} f(y) \\
> &= (1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda f(y) \ \mbox{ by \tag{5} above}.
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Thus we have shown that (1) holds for all real numbers $\lambda$ of the form in (2) above. Am I right?
>
> Now let $x, y \in (a, b)$ be arbitrary, and let $g$ be the mapping of $\mathbb{R}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^1$ defined by the equation 
>   $$ g(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda f(y) - f\left( (1-\lambda) x+ \lambda y \right) \ \mbox{ for all } \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$$
>   Then since $f$ is continuous in $(a, b)$, therefore $g$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$.
>
> Moreover all real numbers $\lambda$ of the form (2) are in the inverse image under $g$ of the infinite closed interval $[0, +\infty)$, and this interval is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^1$. This due to the continuity of $g$ on $[0, 1]$ implies that the inverse image under $g$ of $[0, +\infty)$ is also a closed set in $[0, 1]$ and hence a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^1$, because $[0, 1]$ is itself a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Am I right?

What next? How to complete this proof from here?

Is the continuity of $f$ essential for the conclusion to hold?

Comment: Overall, the statement is false if continuity is omitted -- solid attempt in any case after a quick, but careful, glance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact that dyadic numbers of the form (2) are dense (see [dyadic dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23039/how-can-i-show-that-the-set-of-rational-numbers-with-denominator-a-power-of-two)) in $(0,1)$, so for every $\lambda\in (0,1)$ you can find a sequence $\lambda_n\to\lambda$ with $\lambda_n$ of the form (2). You apply (1) with $\lambda_n$ and then use continuity to let $n\to\infty$.
Yes you need continuity. Take a look at [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)
The same kind of pathologies occur here.
Take a look at this [midpoint convex](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-discontinuous-midpoint-convex-function/)

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't checked as a solution, or up-voted.  Your solution is indeed a sketch of the proof of the original statement asked by the OP, to which the statement is false if continuity is omitted.

Comment: No problem -- the "midpoint convex" link proving the existence of a discontinuous, midpoint-convex function is profoundly interesting...I knew of their existence, but I never saw a rigorous proof until today. Loads of info in your post.