# Treatise on foundational mathematics

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I read the construction of real numbers by Dedekind cuts today in a book(it was quite incomplete).I was wondering if someone could please point me to a source or a book containing the construction of the entire natural numbers,the rationals, the real numbers and the various operations like addition, subtraction, exponentiation and all that. I may not read it whole at one go but I certainly wish to see how it is done.In addition, a few "exercises" or something of that sort will not do me harm.

Thanks!

Comment: I start from the natural numbers in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/in-set-theory-how-are-real-numbers-represented-as-sets/62868#62868). I'm sure you can find detailed constructions of the natural numbers on the internet somewhere too.

Comment: for dedekind, http://books.google.com/books?id=PywPAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dedekind+real+numbers&source=bl&ots=M79IBx6ofg&sig=Pb1jsc2Xraq5XVJNvqnWy0gjSko&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2w1RUJC-MunFyAHi4IHYDQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dedekind%20real%20numbers&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goldrei's "Classic Set Theory" is a great introduction! The first few chapters are dedicated to this.

Comment: I don't know why these answers have not yet received upvotes.But this is precisely what I was looking for.Thanks for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/fawaz/481files/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf) you will find a book that contains the construction. It is an appendix to chapter 1.