# Set Theory (Real Numbers)

Tags: real-numbers

I have seen in a book that a number whose square is nonnegative is called real number. How can we explain what a real number is?

Comment: From Wikipedia: The currently standard axiomatic definition is that real numbers form the unique Archimedean complete totally ordered field (R ; + ; · ; <), up to an isomorphism.

Comment: That's a slightly perverse definition of the reals. It is the case though that the subset of the complex numbers with that property (when squared is a nonegative real number) are real numbers. However, it is circular! To define the reals from the ground up, there is a standard set of postulates/axioms. See for example, Spivak's Calculus for a careful discussion.

Comment: Ok, but I need a simple answer

Comment: You are trying to define "real numbers" using the term "real numbers"( or similar to that. At least you have to specify among what numbers.. Anyway it would cost a lot more than defining real numbers directly since you are trying to define it as a sub-object)  It's nonsense..

Comment: Perhaps you should read the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/in-set-theory-how-are-real-numbers-represented-as-sets?rq=1).  Adequately defining the reals is generally not going to be "simple", but even without knowing the exact definition, you should know how to manipulate them.

Comment: Assuming from your tag and your title ("Set Theory"), I can only assume that you want to define real numbers using set theory. There is no particularly simple way to do it.

Comment: The "simplest" way to define real numbers in a single line is as **the complete ordered field**.

Comment: @ZeroXLR you need to add "with the archimedean property", otherwise the hyperreals and surreals (and presumably a lot of in-between fields) would also qualify.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Thank you for the fix.

Comment: It is not a good characterization. Many reasons. Note that the square of $3+i$ is non-negative.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, you are wrong. The square of 3+iota is a complex number.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah: Indeed it is complex and non-real.  It is also non-negative, in the sense that it is not negative.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, What do you mean by non-negative? If a real number is non-negative then it would either be positive or zero but we can't discuss that in complex numbers.

Comment: I was objecting to the formulation. of the quoted "definition" of real number.  If it had said "positive or $0$" it would have been OK, though not useful.  But as I read it, the reasonable interpretation of "non-negative" is "not negative."