# Dedekind and Cauchy completeness

Tags: real-numbers, complete-spaces, ordered-fields

I know that the following equivalence holds:
$$\text{Cauchy-complete ordered Archimedean field}\Leftrightarrow\text{Dedekind-complete ordered field}$$
I would like to know some concrete examples of a Cauchy-complete ordered field that is not Dedekind-complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic example: the Cauchy-completion of a non-Archimedean ordered field (see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160280)).

Concrete example: the Laurent series ring $\mathbb{R}((x))$ (see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331067) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3369354)). In fact, the proof does not use any special properties of the reals, so we have the following extension:

**Proposition 1.** *Let $R$ be an ordered field. Then $R((x))$, ordered by the positive cone*
$$ R((x))_+ = \{0\} \cup \left\{\sum_{i=k}^\infty \alpha_i x^i \, : \, \alpha_k > 0\right\}, $$
*is a Cauchy-complete ordered field.*

The unit $1 \in R((x))$, and therefore the prime field $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq R((x))$, are contained in the subfield $R = \{\alpha_ix^0 \, : \, \alpha_i \in R\} \subseteq R((x))$, so it is clear from the definition that $x^{-1} > q$ ($\, = qx^0$) for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore:

**Proposition 2.** *Let $R$ be an ordered field. Then $R((x))$, ordered as in Proposition 1, is not Archimedean.*

Answer (score 4):

The set
$$\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q})):=\{f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}\ |\ supp(f)\mbox{ is well-ordered}\},$$
where $supp(f):=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}\ | \ f(x)\neq 0\}$,
is a field under the addition and multiplication defined as follows:
for every $f,g\in \mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}$,

1. $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$,
2. $fg(x):=\displaystyle\sum_{a+b=x}f(a)g(b)$

Consider $\lambda:\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{Q}$,
$\lambda(f)=\min\{supp(f)\}$.
For $f,g\in \mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ we define:
$$f<g\Leftrightarrow f\neq g\mbox{ and }(g-f)(\lambda(g-f))>0.$$
Then $(\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q})),\leq)$ is a non-Archimedean ordered field called **Hann field**.

If the map $|\;\;|:\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))\to \mathbb{Q}$ is defined by
$$ |f|:=\begin{cases}
        e^{-\min\{supp(f)\}}&, f\neq 0 \\
              0 &, f=0 ,
     \end{cases}
 $$
then $(\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q})),|\;\;|)$ is a Cauchy-complete
non-Archimedean valued field.

It is important to say that the order topology and the valuation topology coincide.

Another good example is the **Levi-Civita field**.
$$\mathcal{R}:=\{f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R} \:\vert\:
 supp(f)\cap(-\infty,n]\mbox{ is finite for every }n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$.
When we restrict the valuation of $\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ to $\mathcal{R}$,
the latter becomes a Cauchy-complete,
non-Archimedean valued field. Similarly, it is also a non-Archimedean ordered field.

Both fields are real-closed field extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ and their complexifications $\mathbb{C}((\mathbb{Q}))$ and $\mathcal{R}+i\mathcal{R}$ are algebraically closed.
Also, $\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ is the spherical completion of $\mathcal{R}$. The technical details and more information can be found in *Comicheo, A. Barría, and K. Shamseddine. "Summary on non-archimedean valued fields." Advances in Ultrametric Analysis Contemp. Math 704 (2018): 1-36.*

Comment: This answer complements Josse's in the following sense: while the Laurent Series field $\mathbb{R}((x))$ can be considered as a non-Archimedean valued field with a discrete valuation, the Levi-Civita field $\mathcal{R}$ and the Hahn field $\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ are non-Archimedean valued fields with a dense valuation. As ordered fields, they form a sequence of field extensions $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}((x))\subset\mathcal{R}\subset\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$.