# How is $\mathbb{Q}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ given the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ based on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So, oftentimes it is said that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, but how is this the case when $\mathbb{R}$ is constructed out of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$? Would it not be better said, "the representations of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are a subset of $\mathbb{R}$," which is obvious?

Comment: If you prefer ,you can just say that there is a natural injection of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb R$, which is compatible with the arithmetic sructures.

Comment: Such things happen all the time in mathematics. Similarly, you can say that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, just that $\mathbb{Q}$ contains a subset which is basically a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. Thing is, the sets are the same up to naturally changing the names of the elements, and have the same properties. So we just identify them.

Comment: You are correct. The same is true when we say $\mathbb R\subset \mathbb C$.

Comment: The right way to think about $\mathbb{R}$ is as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. Informally, this is akin to filling in the gaps between rational numbers, and this is why we usually say that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$, but what we mean is that we can identify $\mathbb{Q}$ with a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Technically yes, but I think the point is that algebraic structures like $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$, etc are more usefully identified by their *algebraic souls* than by the specific appearance of their elements. So saying $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ really just means that the algebraic soul of $\mathbb{Q}$ is canonically reflected in that of $\mathbb{R}$. However, at some point it saves more time to stop interpreting $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ as a suggestion and start interpreting it literally.

Comment: I dunno, are you a platonist or a formalist? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend regarding the construction of the real numbers from the natural numbers a proof of the existence of a complete ordered field (based on the axioms of set theory) - not a definition of the real numbers. The real numbers are defined up to a natural isomorphism by the characterization as a complete ordered field, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12009/572841) answer.

Comment: Thank you for the link :)

Comment: @kahen This must be the most unexpected comment I ever got. Your answer helped me a lot, so thank you!