# Meaning of ℝ (\$\Bbb{R}\$)

Tags: real-numbers

What is the meaning of "blackboard bold" letters, such as $\Bbb{R}$ (written in MathJax as `$\Bbb{R}$`)?

I saw this letter here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

...and in a machine learning text like this:
[image]

*Any other insight beyond [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4538258/454133) is more-than-welcome. I'm new on this site, and this is my first attempt in life to truly begin to understand the meaning of mathematical symbols.*

*In college, I was ["downvoted" and made fun of too](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6785843875429920768/), and my 25k experience on Stack Overflow tells me to expect the same thing here, but keep in mind I'm doing my best here to learn. I'm watching 12 hours of machine learning videos, for heaven's sakes!*

Comment: I expected the downvote. I was downvoted in college for my questions in-person too. I don't know how else to learn this stuff though. Please provide help and resources to help me figure this stuff out.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of the [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

Comment: I guess the issue is this site expects some certain pre-requisite knowledge

Comment: Looks like a possible candidate for [SE Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: The history  was that printed books could include bold letters, while professors would be teaching on the blackboard (not sure when that started)  and found drawing a single extra stroke was less messy than   shading in a whole letter. Common for $Z, Q, R, C$  Eventually it caught on.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Hmm. We accept some very basic questions here. It’s more that a willingness to explain the problem is needed. The OP says they know it means the set of reals: so what is the problem?

Comment: @WillJagy or even a short chalk stick held flat and a single stroke. In typography though, there is a needs to disambiguate fonts.

Comment: @WeatherVane, this is not a puzzling question. I'm asking a straight-forward question looking for a straight-forward, normal math, answer, without pedantic debate. It would be like me asking, "What is zero", and you say, "that's a puzzling question", when all I really need to know is "zero means you have nothing of something"--regardless of the pedantry involved by pedagocic pedantics who would nitpick that to death.

Comment: In the context of machine learning, $\Bbb R$ may simply be a stylized way to write **R**, the computer language. See [Introduction to Machine Learning with R](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/introduction-to-machine/9781491976432/).

Comment: Aside: I haven't nit-picked or been pedantic. "Going off on one" or having no SOH will get you ribbed like you were in college.

Answer (score 4):

Conventionally $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers. Similarly $\Bbb Z$ is the set of all integers, $\Bbb C$ is the set of all complex numbers, and $\Bbb N$ is the set of all natural numbers. Other number systems use similar notation.

Comment: This is helpful. Upvoted. Can you be more specific and help me understand concretely what is "the set of all real numbers?" I can tell someone that `*` in C is a "dereference to a pointer", but that is all meaningless without further explanation. I'd appreciate a longer explanation for each of the things you mentioned.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Have you read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)?

Comment: @GabrielStaples: I don't know why you were downvoted; I don't think that was right. That being said, I think that the question you're asking in your comment is distinct enough from your original question to warrant searching this site separately. Your original post is asking about the meaning of the notation $\mathbb{R}$; this comment question is asking about what real numbers *are*, which is another thing entirely (and much deeper). I'm sure it has been addressed previously, but if you can't find an answer, ask a separate question, thanks!

Comment: @BrianTung, sounds good.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Note that I have changed my advice to first checking if that question has been asked on this site. I rather suspect it has. But if you don't find a satisfactory answer, ask a new question, but clarify why the existing answers don't help you.

Comment: @BrianTung, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4538280/454133

Comment: @GabrielStaples   people have gotten very good with this search thing called approach0.   You can read about it in the results of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=approach0   I seem to remember some examples with precise syntax  given among Meta posts.

Comment: Let's start with something easier. Do you know what I mean when I say ${\Bbb N} = \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe, no I don't know what you mean by that, unfortunately. I need to learn: A) How do I read that out-loud--meaning: what to say vocally or in my head when I see that, and B) what does it mean.

Answer (score 1):

In view of your programming background, you can think of the usual number sets as types.

Real numbers are all the numbers we can write with an infinitely long decimal expansion. This is approximated in actual computers with the type "float". Of course this is an approximation because the set of real numbers is infinite but our RAM is finite.

Saying that the distance function maps a pair of images to a real number is akin to a function declaration saying that the distance function takes two arguments of the type "image" and return one element of the type "real".

Answer (score -1):

*This answer modified for correctness since all 4 downvotes. If still wrong, please explain why. I'd like to fix it.*

The best I could find was that $\Bbb{R}$ means "the set of real numbers" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold#Usage).

And a "set" is just a collection of "things": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics).

So, even though "a set of real numbers" could be a list or `std::vector<>` (in C++) of real numbers, such as this:

$some\_set = \{1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$

...**the** set of real numbers is an infinitely-long list of ALL real numbers, including **all** fractions and fractional numbers, and **all** numbers with an infinite number of decimal places.

From [@Xiobiq's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538257/meaning-of-%e2%84%9d-bbbr/4538258?noredirect=1#comment9540615_4538257) with this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number:

[image]

Here are some quotes from the link above (emphasis added):

> Real numbers can be thought of as points on an **infinitely long number line.**

> In mathematics, a real number is a value of a continuous quantity that can represent a distance along a line (or alternatively, a quantity that can be represented as an infinite decimal expansion).

> **The real numbers** include **all** the rational numbers, such as the integer −5 and the fraction 4/3, and **all** the irrational numbers, such as ${\sqrt {2}}$ (1.41421356..., the square root of 2, an irrational algebraic number). Included within the irrationals are the real transcendental numbers, such as π (3.14159265...).[2] Real numbers can be used to measure (approximately) physical observables such as time, mass, energy; and in one dimension, distance, velocity, acceleration, force, momentum, etc. **The set of real numbers is denoted using the symbol R or {\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }\mathbb {R} [3] and is sometimes called "the reals".[4]**

Comment: No. No computer can handle even the integers, never mind the reals. The reals include $\pi$, for instance, all irrational numbers, etc

Comment: It's not "a" set of real numbers, it's "the" set of real numbers. It's all of them, not just some of them.

Comment: @FShrike, can you explain? I don't know what you mean when you say a computer can't store a set of real numbers.

Comment: @Filippo, can you please explain? Consider adding an answer. What's a set? What's a field?

Comment: @AmaanM, ok, now we are getting somewhere. This is useful. I didn't understand that nuance. So, if it is **all** real numbers, then it is an infinitely long list, and contains numbers with an infinite number of decimal places, right?

Comment: It's **the** set of real numbers, not **some** set. Nothing to do with decimal notation.

Comment: @Filippo $\mathbb{R}$ is a set. It is also a group, a ring and a field. Every field is also a set (looking at its elements).

Comment: @WeatherVane, I don't understand what you're talking about. I'm going to need a more-thorough answer please. Consider adding an answer. You're talking at a PhD math professor level to a student with only the normal MS in ME level of math background.

Comment: @Xiobiq  "Every field is also a set (looking at its elements)" - Yes, each field has a set associated to it, but this doesn't mean that a field is equal to a set. A field consists of a set **and** some operations.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I mean that you cannot store the (infinite) set of real numbers on a computer, irrespective of their representation.

Comment: @Filippo Well, this is just being over pedantic for no good reason. To be accurate, actually $\mathbb{R}$ **is** the **set** of the real numbers, and not the field.

Comment: @Xiobiq I disagree.

Comment: @GabrielStaples To be precise, $\mathbb R$ is actually an **ordered** field, i.e. a field together with an ordering. And not some arbitrary ordered field, but a **complete** ordered field. This defines $\mathbb R$ up to a natural isomorphism. Read all about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12009/572841).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Filippo Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) agrees: "The set of real numbers is denoted using the symbol **R** or $\mathbb{R}$". Also the general notation (which is also present in this question) is $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which means a function from the set of the real numbers to the set of the real numbers. So, yeah.

Comment: @Xiobiq Well, it isn't a surprise that we use the same symbol for the ordered field and the set associated to it, is it? We do this all the time...If I say "Let $V$ be a vector field", then I certainly won't introduce a new symbol for the set associated to $V$ later on... Again, the structure of an ordered field is important because it **defines** $\mathbb R$ (up to a natural isomorphism...what more can you expect?).

Comment: We can essentially say that $\mathbb R$ is **the** complete ordered field...

Comment: @GabrielStaples there's a lot going on in these comments that's irrelevant to your needs. It's the set of real numbers. It's an infinitely long list. It includes natural numbers like 1, 2, 3, it includes rational numbers like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, it includes irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\pi$ and $e$, and it includes all of these numbers' negative counterparts. Every number you can think of that doesn't have an $i$ in it. That's all you need.

Comment: @AmaanM, thank you. Make that an answer and I'll upvote it.